# How to specify an ignore pattern with ack?

Tags: shell, grep, ack, piping

I'm trying to search for lines containing 'foo' but these lines must not contain 'bar'. What's a good way to search with these parameters with `ack`?

I can do:

`ack "foo" | grep -v "bar"`

but it doesn't keep the nicely layed-out and coloured output of `ack`. Also, `grep` doesn't have good support for Perl regexes, unlike `ack`.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, terribly sorry. I corrected that a couple of mins after posting the question by for some reason it didn't persist.

Comment: You can not use `awk`? It will do this with ease.

Comment: @Jotne `ack` is more suited for searching text files, particularly source code, and has a lot of features suited for this that make it a better tool for such tasks than `awk`. e.g. `awk` only supports POSIX ERE which is kind of a deal-breaker for me; on the other hand, `ack` supports Perl regex.

Comment: Regex is not always important. I see again and again problem solved using `awk` without using regex.  If your system does have `awk` try it out using `time` to see what is fastest like this `time awk '/foo/ && !/bar/' file`  Then you can make a selection based on `portability`  `easy to understand` and `speed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a slightly more complicated regular expression:

```
ack '^(?!.*bar).*(foo)' file
```

The `(?!...)` does a negative lookahead to ensure that "bar" is not on the line. Here's how it works:

- `^` Start at beginning of the line.
- `(?!.*bar)` Advance any number of characters until "bar" is found. If it is found, do not continue. Otherwise, return to the start of the line and continue.
- `.*(foo)` Match (and capture) "foo" at any point between the beginning and end of the line.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
other foo bar
baz foo other
$ ack '^(?!.*bar).*(foo)' file
baz foo other
```

Comment: Unlike the alternative suggestion of @jcl's answer this highlights only the search term instead of the whole line. I can try make an `ack` wrapper out of this somehow so that I don't have to type out that long regex. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The reason that only the word is highlighted is because I have surrounded it in a capturing group `(foo)`. If you remove the parentheses, the whole line will be highlighted.

Comment: Please could you explain why lines with "bar" are ignored even if their position in the line is after "foo"? I thought that a lookbehind looks *behind* the match pattern.

Comment: Sure, I have added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use `ack` itself for the exclusion pass, and to reverse the order of invocation:

```
ack -v "bar" | ack "foo"
```

That will at least highlight the search term, although it won't get you quite the same formatting as just `ack "foo"` does.

Another possibility is to pack the two terms together in the same regex, using a negative lookahead for the exclusion term, as given in this answer:

[Multiple patterns with ack-grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188879/multiple-patterns-with-ack-grep/6189375#6189375)

```
ack '^(?!.*bar).*foo.*$'
```

That will get you `ack`'s per-file formatting, but the whole line will be highlighted as the search term.